# Basic Java OOP Questions on variable declaration and access 

Tags: java, oop

If I have a class `Person` which has two instance variables: `name` of type `String` and `friend` of type `Person`, how can I add a method to Person that will allow me to access the `name` of the friend belonging to an instance of `Person`?

Also, more generally in Java can:

- Local variables can be declared private?
- Formal parameters may be declared final?
- Does declaring an object automatically allocate space for it?

Comment: Obvious homework.  Try asking your TA.

Comment: You'd think finding SO and typing all that in would be more work than looking up the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:
  Honestly, this is the most basic practical object-oriented question out there.  If you don't understand it, you need to go talk to someone.

True or False: Local variables may be declared private.
  Local variables can never be accessed by outside code; it makes no sense to declare them private.

True or False: Formal parameters may be declared to be final.
  True - it means that the method can't reassign the parameter locally.
      /* Edited according to the comment below */

True or False: Declaring an object (for example, Person p;) allocates space for that object
  Objects in java are all references.  When you declare an object, it allocates a reference which doesn't refer to anything in particular.  When you later allocate the object, it then sets that reference to point to an allocated section of memory in which the object is stored.

Comment: Thank you sam, really appreciate the reply and will follow your advice

Comment: -1 You state that the `final` keyword means the method won't modify the content of the object passed in. This is not true. The mutability or immutability of an object is not monitored by the compiler or JVM. The `final` keyword simply means the method can not reassign a different object to that same parameter reference. There is really no reason to ever do this as the change is not reflected outside of the method's scope so a best practice would be to make every parameter final (IMO).

Comment: Sorry about that - I was thinking more semantically speaking, rather than what's enforced by the JVM.